# Ad Colony ads run just one time

Tags: java, android, ads, adcolony

Problem : Whenever I run application on a new mobile, my ad loads and runs perfectly where I want it to run. But after that on same mobile ad video doesn't play, even after I un-install my application and install again.

I don't want to show ads on my main activity, but I want to load ads in that activity. That's why I have added this in my main activity class

```
implements AdColonyAdListener, AdColonyAdAvailabilityListener
```

and override its methods like this.

```
    @Override
public void onAdColonyAdAvailabilityChange(boolean isAvailable, String arg1) {
    AdColonyHelper.isAdvAvailable = isAvailable;
}

@Override
public void onAdColonyAdAttemptFinished(AdColonyAd arg0) {

}

@Override
public void onAdColonyAdStarted(AdColonyAd arg0) {

}
```

To track the availability of ad I have a static boolean variable in my AdColonyHelper class. AdColony Helper class:

```
package Helpers;
import android.app.Activity;
import com.jirbo.adcolony.AdColonyAdListener;
import com.jirbo.adcolony.AdColonyVideoAd;

public class AdColonyHelper {
public static boolean isAdvAvailable = false;   
public static String APP_ID;
public static String ZONE_ID;

static Activity act = new Activity();

public static void setting(String appid, String zoneId, Activity myAct)
{
    APP_ID  = appid;
    ZONE_ID = zoneId;
    act = myAct;
}

public static void showAdv(boolean isAvailable)
{
    isAdvAvailable = isAvailable;
    if(isAdvAvailable)
    {
        AdColonyVideoAd ad = new AdColonyVideoAd(ZONE_ID);//.withListener( (AdColonyAdListener) act );
        ad.show();
    }
}

public static void showAdv()
{       
    if(isAdvAvailable)
    {
        AdColonyVideoAd ad = new AdColonyVideoAd(ZONE_ID).withListener( (AdColonyAdListener) act );
        ad.show();
    }
}

}
```

in on create of my main activity I initialize it like this

```
AdColony.configure( this, "version:1.0,store:google", APP_ID, ZONE_ID );       
    AdColony.addAdAvailabilityListener(this);       
    if ( !AdColony.isTablet() )
    {
      setRequestedOrientation( ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT );
    }
    // below line is to set static variables in class
    AdColonyHelper.setting(APP_ID, ZONE_ID, this);
```

This is all what I have done for ads in my main activity. Now right after going to my second Activity. I have this in on create method of that activity.

```
    AdColonyHelper.showAdv();
```

This checks the availability of ad and plays it. But it plays ad just only one time.
But I continuously see this in my logcat

`01-08 14:12:15.579: I/AdColony(23623): Finished downloading:
01-08 14:12:15.609: I/AdColony(23623): https://androidads21.adcolony.com/configure?......`

Comment: Did yo try to call  AdColonyHelper.showAdv(); from onAdColonyAdAvailabilityChange ? I have similar issue but not with all the phones, showing the add when entering on onAdColonyAdAvailabilityChange. Did you finally solve the problem?

Comment: I think the Availability change when you leave the mainActivity?